# PHP: concatenation of multidimensional array elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I want to concatenate one element of a multidimensional array with some strings.

```
<?
$string1 = 'dog';
$string2 = array
           (
            'farm' => array('big'=>'cow', 'small'=>'duck'),
            'jungle' => array('big'=>'bear', 'small'=>'fox')
           );
$string3 = 'cat';
$type = 'farm';
$size = 'big';
$string = "$string1 $string2[$type][$size] $string3";
echo($string);
?>
```

By using this syntax for $string, I get:

dog Array[big] cat

I would like not to use the alternate syntax

```
$string = $string1 . ' ' . $string2[$type][$size] . ' ' . $string3;
```

which works.

What's wrong with "$string1 $string2[$type][$size] $string3"?

Comment: to concatenate strings you should use . sign $string=$string1.$string2[$type][$size].$string3;

Comment: @fsonmezay, the OP is aware of how concatenation works.

Answer (score 6):

Use the "complex syntax":

```
$string = "$string1 {$string2[$type][$size]} $string3";
```

PHP's variable parsing is quite simple. It will recognize one level array access, but not more level. By enclosing the expression in `{}` you explicitly state which part of the string is a variable.

See [PHP - Variable parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: Felix, Thank you very much for your fast response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of complex syntax, or variable parsing in strings.  Normally I would use the "alternate" syntax you described.  You could do this as well:

```
$string = implode(' ', array($string1, $string2[$type][$size], $string3));
```

Comment: Interesting approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$string = "$string1 {$string2[$type][$size]} $string3";
```