# php array multi-dimensional indexing

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I am pretty green when it comes to php, so here's a basic question for which I have not found an answer yet.

I extract repetitive information from a page by doing regex matching as follows. The regex has two capturing groups (...), hence the `$matches` array has index ranging from 0 (full regex value) to 2 ( 1 and 2 are the capturing group values).

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents(url);
    preg_match_all(regex-with-two-capturing-groups, $page, $matches);
    $m1 = $matches[1];
    $m2 = $matches[2];
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($m1); $i++) {
        echo ("<tr><td>$m1[$i]</td><td>$m2[$i]</td></tr>");
    }
?>
```

This works fine, but at first I tried a shorter version:

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents(url);
    preg_match_all(regex-with-two-capturing-groups, $page, $matches);
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($matches[0]); $i++) {
        echo ("<tr><td>$matches[1][$i]</td><td>$matches[2][$i]</td></tr>");
    }
?>
```

but this resulted in

```
<tr><td>Array[0]</td><td>Array[0]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Array[1]</td><td>Array[1]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Array[2]</td><td>Array[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Array[3]</td><td>Array[3]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Array[4]</td><td>Array[4]</td></tr>
...
```

Why is this?
And is there a way to do two-dimensional indexing in one expression, not having to define intermediate arrays m1 and m2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php
    $page = file_get_contents(url);
    preg_match_all(regex-with-two-capturing-groups, $page, $matches);
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($matches[0]); $i++) {
        echo ("<tr><td>".$matches[1][$i]."</td><td>".$matches[2][$i]."</td></tr>");
    }
?>
```

PHP Documentation : [language.types.string.parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Look also here : [PHP: concatenation of multidimensional array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886388/php-concatenation-of-multidimensional-array-elements)

Comment: All right, so . (dot) is sort of a string concatenate operator?

Comment: @Maestro13 : Maybe because of multi-dimensional array qualifier.Always use . as concatenation, it increase readability of your code and prevents you from solving such issues.See my updated answer.